# Rails：Couldn't find all Post with 'id': (false, true) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a system for category search.
At that time, the following errors are occurring in the current system.

`Couldn't find all Post with 'id': (false, true) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2).`

Controllers

```
def category
  @category = params[:category_name]
  @posts=Post.find(PostCategory.group(:post_id).pluck(:@category))
  #↑The error point.
end
```

routes

```
get '/category/:category_name', to: 'pages#category'
```

Views

```
<li><a href="category/casual">casual</a></li>
<li><a href="category/natural">natural</a></li>
<li><a href="category/clean">clean</a></li>
<li><a href="category/rock">rock</a></li>
<li><a href="category/formal">formal</a></li>
<li><a href="category/street">street</a></li>
<li><a href="category/hip_hop">hip_hop</a></li>
<li><a href="category/sports">sports</a></li>
<li><a href="category/outdoors">outdoors</a></li>
<li><a href="category/surf">surf</a></li>
```

Relationship of models

```
belongs_to :post
has_one :post_category
accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_category
```

PostCategory table

```
create_table "post_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "casual", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "natural", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "clean", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "rock", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "formal", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "street", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "hip_hop", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "sports", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "outdoors", default: false, null: false
    t.boolean "surf", default: false, null: false
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_post_categories_on_post_id"
  end
```

### What I want to do

Example.
I want to find a column where `category_name params(casual)` and `PostCategory column(casual)` are the same, and from there, find only the ones that are true, and retrieve all the records of `Post` whose `post_id` corresponds to `PostCategory column(casual, only true)` and reflect them in the view.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's a problem in your `category` method where it says `:@category`. That would probably need to say `@category` (without the colon), so that the method body's second line reads:

```rb
@posts=Post.find(PostCategory.group(:post_id).pluck(@category))
                                                    ^
```

That aside, it seems that you're trying to fetch all posts that belong to a certain category. What you're doing right now won't work because your query returns an array of booleans, and then you use booleans to look up posts. But you'd need ids to look up posts because you can't pass booleans to `Post.find`.

Why not just do (not tested):

```rb
@posts = Post.find(PostCategory.where(@category => true).pluck(:post_id))
```

or, in a single query (not tested either):

```rb
@posts = Post.joins(:post_category).where("post_categories.#{@category}" => true)
```

But for that last one you may need to check the `@category` variable against a whitelist to avoid injections. EDIT: As Max suggests in the comments, you may want to change the where clause to `where( post_categories: {  @category => true })` to avoid injections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It's a very elementary mistake and I've been struggling with it.
I'm glad I posted it here. Thank you very much for your kindness.

Comment: `"post_categories.#{@category}"` could be a potential SQL injection volunerability? `where( post_categories: {  @category => true })` is slightly better.

Comment: @max I had already pointed out that it may be abused for injections.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution which doesn't require you to modify the database to add categories would be to just setup a more sane normalization table / join table setup:

```
# rails g model category name:string:uniq
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations

  validates :name, 
     uniqueness: true,
     presence: true
end

# rails g model categorization post:belongs_to category:belongs_to
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :post

  validates :post_id, 
     uniqueness: { scope: :category_id }
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end
```

The Rails to handle this would either to handle this on the categories#show action (or with a nested route):

```
resources :categories
```

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.find_by!(name: params[:id])
    @posts = @category.posts 
  end
end
```

This of course implies that you have some sort of slugging in place that ensures that the name of the category can be used in the path of a URL. Gems like FriendlyID are your friend here.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a new solution.
I was making a very rudimentary mistake. And your solution has added more knowledge to me. Thank you very much for your kindness!

Comment: Yeah I don't think your solution is actually a viable one as adding categories would be a developer concern and the queries are so strange and inefficient. Overall its a very quirky solution to a problem that been done millions of times already has a widely accepted solution.

Comment: If you want an example of how quirky and inefficient the queries  are going to get consider fetching posts that are tagged with `casual`, `natural` or `clean`. `WHERE post_categories.casual = true OR post_categories.natural = true OR post_categories.clean = true`. VS `WHERE categories.name IN ('casual', 'natural', 'clean')` which can be handled by single db index.

Answer (score 0):

@posts=Post.find(PostCategory.group(:post_id).pluck(:category))